# 1970's PBS SciFi Miniseries

Tags: story-identification, tv

This one's driving me bonkers.

- There was a mid-70's - I'm thinking somewhere between 74-76 +/- year
  on the front-end - which I believe was Canadian-made.
- It was shown here in the States on **PBS** - that I *do* remember.
- The press made a big deal 'bout it.
- For some reason, I'm thinking either Bruce Davidson was in it, or
  someone who looked like him, or - even someone who had the name
  'Bruce' was the male lead.
- I remember a few things - images - there were a lot of shots on some
  flat plaza, & a staircase. The music throughout was a lot of
  synthesiser.
- It was **not** the Kurt Vonnegut show (I don't think I ever saw that,
  but, I *do know* this is **not** that.

That's about all I can recall, & it's driving me nuts, 'cos I can hear the synth theme playing in my head, or, more accurately - pieces of it.

I just joined this site 'cos I'm hoping someone here might recall this.

I tried to put tags - '**PBS  Canadian, Synthesiser**,' but, I wasn't allowed to (as a newbie), so, if anyone can help...

Comment: Can you provide any details at all regarding the story line. Your question as currently posited provides nothing that supports it being sci-fi. Am not doubting you, but if you're sure it's sci-fi. aren't there some remembered details besides the few few vague images you mention ?

Comment: The storyline is a haze (I was about 8-12 years old. It was on at 8p. Big deal for me) - I think the main character was - in some regard - either involved in, or affected by time.

It's hard for me 2 b clear on th@ 'cos it's so fuzzy in my mind. 

Somehow I  think, the main character (might've been) displaced from time - he was in the wrong time stream.

But, wh@ I can say is the series was a more 'cerebral' type (it was early/mid 70's, & - even though it was a 'big' miniseries, it's budget was still PBS, though I do recall them - PBS - making a big deal of it's production values.

Comment: YES - it DEFINITELY WAS SciFi. I'm almost positive the writer of the show was a well-known author (and, again - I never saw the Kurt Vonnegut series  Between Time & Timbuktu - mentioned here, which was broadcast around this time. That I never heard of much less saw). It had very eerie - prominent synthesiser - music played, but, it was sparse - if not nil - on special effects. it was cerebral. Stan: I want to thank you - for even taking time to read this. What I've said I'm POSITIVE about. I don't want to say things I'm not sure of, or can't recall correctly.

Comment: I know you said you don't remember much in the way of storyline, but what about any specific scenes? Maybe something the characters said or talked about?

Answer (score 12):

Given your memory of Bruce Davison being in it, I'm pretty sure it was The Lathe of Heaven (a [PBS adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven_%28film%29) of the [novel by Ursula K. Le Guin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven)), on youtube here:

If you jump to 34:30 in the youtube video you can see a bunch of shots of the giant institute that the psychiatrist eventually works at, whose exterior is probably the "plaza" you remembered.

Comment: The Lathe of Heaven!!! You got it!!! I knew it stared a 'Bruce' and I thought it was Davison. I can't thank you enough! I'm SO happy I found this site and YOU - (fellow) fans. Wowsers - again, much thanks.